# Azure Key Vault: Backup Secrets using PowerShell

Tags: azure, powershell, azure-keyvault

I am trying to run the following PS script to back-up all of the Secrets, in a specific Azure Key Vault:

```
$secret = Get-AzureKeyVaultSecret –VaultName 'testkeyvault-1' |
ForEach-Object {
$Name = $_."Name"
Backup-AzureKeyVaultSecret -Secret $Name -OutputFile 'C:\Backup.blob'
}
```

Though this is failing with the following PS error, any help would be appreciated:

```
Backup-AzureKeyVaultSecret : Cannot bind parameter 'Secret'. Cannot convert  the "SQLSecret" value of type "System.String" to type    "Microsoft.Azure.Commands.KeyVault.Models.Secret".
At line:4 char:36
+ Backup-AzureKeyVaultSecret -Secret $Name -OutputFile 'C:\Backup.blob'
+                                    ~~~~~
+ CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (:) [Backup- AzureKeyVaultSecret], ParameterBindingException
+ FullyQualifiedErrorId :  CannotConvertArgumentNoMessage,Microsoft.Azure.Commands.KeyVault.BackupAzureKeyVaultSecret
```

Comment: Try using `-Secret $_` instead of assigning only the name value.  (Not familiar with this function, so not sure if this will work; but the error implies this is likely the issue).

Comment: Hi thanks for the reply, it sees the argument as null if I add $_                                                                                                                                                                                                       Backup-AzureKeyVaultSecret : Cannot validate argument on parameter 'Secret'. The argument is null or empty. Provide an argument that is not null or empty, and then try the command

Comment: Interesting; that implies that `$_."Name"` would also be returning null (since in PS the property of a null object is itself null)... so I'd have though you should have received the same error when using `$Name` previously...  unless this isn't the first item in the list.

Comment: Try changing `ForEach-Object {` to `Where-Object {$_} | ForEach-Object {`.  i.e. that should filter out any null values in the list.  Od that any would be returned; but maybe that will help.  Beyond that; don't think I can come up with any other good suggestions I'm afraid...

Comment: Hi regarding -Secret $_."Name" I had left the quotes off, included I now get the following output:                                                                                             `Backup-AzureKeyVaultSecret : Cannot bind parameter 'Secret'. Cannot convert the "TestUsername" value of type "System.String" to type "Microsoft.Azure.Commands.KeyVault.Models.Secret".
At line:4 char:36
+ Backup-AzureKeyVaultSecret -Secret $_."Name" -OutputFile 'C:\Backup.b ...                                                                                                                               `

Comment: This is the Azure PS code to back-up a single secret:                                   `PS C:\>$secret = Get-AzureKeyVaultSecret -VaultName 'MyKeyVault' -Name 'MySecret'
                                                                                                                     PS C:\>Backup-AzureKeyVaultSecret -Secret $secret -OutputFile 'C:\Backup.blob'`

Comment: Thanks for the solution John, that worked great, the Key Vault is now backing up as expected and has just completed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
[string]$VaultName = 'testkeyvault-1'
Get-AzureKeyVaultSecret –VaultName $VaultName |
    ForEach-Object {
        Backup-AzureKeyVaultSecret `
            –VaultName $VaultName `
            -Name $_."Name" `
            -OutputFile ('C:\Backup_{0}.blob' -f $_."Name")
    }
```

Related documentation:

- [Get-AzureKeyVaultSecret](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/azurerm.keyvault/get-azurekeyvaultsecret?view=azurermps-5.2.0)
- [Backup-AzureKeyVaultSecret](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/azurerm.keyvault/backup-azurekeyvaultsecret?view=azurermps-5.2.0)

Comment: Important note: You can restore a backed-up secret to any key vault in the subscription that it was backed up from.

Answer (score 0):

You are missing the parameter "Vault Name" inside the LOOP