# Restore All secret to Azure Key Vault

Tags: azure, azure-keyvault

I have to restore all blob files to the same key vault from where i backed up the files. I have backed up the files using the referenced website. Then deleted all the secrets and now 'restore all' is not working.I can restore individual secrets but not all of them at once.

I am trying following script.

```
[string]$VaultName = 'NewVault' 
Get-AzureKeyVaultSecret -VaultName $VaultName | ForEach-Object { 

Restore-AzureKeyVaultSecret -VaultName $VaultName -InputFile ('C:\Backup1\backup_{0}.blob' -f $_."Name") 

}
```

Reference

[Azure Key Vault: Backup Secrets using PowerShell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48598673/azure-key-vault-backup-secrets-using-powershell)

Comment: the script from the link you've shared is doing the opposite: backup secrets from key vault .

Comment: It is not restoring to the same key vault, it runs and does not give any error and then completes. Restoration of individual secret is working fine

Comment: You are correct, i took the reference from the link, backed up all secrets, then tried restore by changing some values. Now need help as it is not working.

Comment: it's still not clear what you have. You're changing locally and want to send to key vault the updated version? You've changed in the key vault and wants to override the previous version locally? Please be more specific and edit your question

Comment: updated my question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to restore all secrets in a folder to keyvault, you could use the script below.

```
[string]$VaultName = 'joykeyvault'
$files = Get-ChildItem C:\Backup1 -Filter Backup_*.blob -Recurse | % { $_.FullName }
foreach($file in $files){
   Restore-AzureKeyVaultSecret -VaultName $VaultName -InputFile $file  
}
```

*Note*: In the screenshot, I use the new `Az` command `Restore-AzKeyVaultSecret`, in your case, you are using the old `AzureRM` module, so just use `Restore-AzureKeyVaultSecret`.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

One thing you can check is if the Azure Key Vault is soft-deleted

> Upon deleting a key vault object, such as a key, the service will
> place the object in a deleted state, making it inaccessible to any
> retrieval operations. While in this state, the key vault object can
> only be listed, recovered, or forcefully/permanently deleted.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/key-vault/general/soft-delete-overview#key-vault-object-recovery

You can check this with this command from Azure Cloud Shell:

```
az keyvault list-deleted
```

If you have a soft-deleted key vault it will show up as a:

```
"type": "Microsoft.KeyVault/deletedVaults"
```

You can then recover the complete vault like this:

```
az keyvault recover --name <key-vault-name>
```

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/keyvault?view=azure-cli-latest